# Printing all records in a mongoDB Collection Golang

Tags: mongodb, go

I've got a MongoDB Collection `collection := db.Collection("JobBacklog")` that I'm trying to print out into the console. The DB is in a Docker container and controlling it with a script written in Go.

From what I've been able to find from the mongo-go-driver https://godoc.org/github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo
there is a way to do this but my code keeps returning `document is nil` when I know it isn't.

This is my code I'm using to try to iterate through a collection called `JobBacklog`

```
cur, err := collection.Find(context.Background(), nil)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        defer cur.Close(context.Background())
        for cur.Next(context.Background()) {
            raw, err := cur.DecodeBytes()
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            //print element data from collection
            fmt.Println("Element", raw, x)
        }
        if err := cur.Err(); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
```

I expect it to print out the contents of the collection which are:

```
_id:5c2d34e36657ba3238374f9a
UID:"ALDK"
PROFILE:"B"
STATUS:"PENDING"
DEVICE:"2.2.2.2"
```

That is an example entry of the JobBacklog DB.

Full disclosure, the end goal for this is to find the last entry that was added to the collection, but I need to be able to read through the collection first.

I know I'm connected to the DB, I can add/find/delete entries, but the printing out of all in the collection is eluding me. 
Any assistance is appreciated. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The error message "document is nil' is about the filter in the Find().  Change the line

`cur, err := collection.Find(context.Background(), nil)`

to

`cur, err := collection.Find(context.Background(), bson.D{{}})`

should work.

Answer (score -3):

```
db.Collection("JobBacklog").find({},function(err,result){
console.log(result);
})
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Please take some time to read [answer]. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion

Comment: The question is tagged `Go`, the asker wants a Go solution. This is not valid Go code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this isn't in Go and when I convert it to Go I get the same issue of `document is nil`